# Not returning valid JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So, I'm using node.js and trying to create a simple express REST API, using node-mysql, express (of course), and other things.

I've pretty much had no issues untill now, whenever I execute a db query, it returns an result as such:

```
[ { id: 18,
username: 'test',
passwordHash: 'redacted',
admin: 0,
created: Fri Jun 13 2014 17:17:10 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) } ]
```

JSON.parse, when used on this, returns a `SyntaxError: Unexpected Token o`.
I've looked into JSON validators, which states this is invalid JSON. Am I missing something here, it appears to be JSON. I'm slightly new to JavaScript, so apologies if this is easy.

Comment: That's not JSON. That's a JavaScript object. Unless it passes [a lint test](http://jsonlint.com/) there's no reason `JSON.parse` should be required to handle it.

Comment: It sounds like the value you are trying to pass to `JSON.parse` is already an object, not a string. The value you posted is certainly not JSON. JSON is a **textual** data exchange format with a very specific syntax (e.g. keys must be strings). You can find examples of valid JSON on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json. So, in your case, just don't use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: SO: a pretty good JSON validator.

Comment: @tadman Ah, that makes alot more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is *not* JSON.**

It is *almost* valid JavaScript object literal notation (after which JSON is named), but even there it's missing a few things, such as quotation marks around the `created` string.

In fact it seems that you have a JavaScript object already; passing that to `JSON.parse` will coerce it into a string, which is `[object <some type>]`, the first invalid/unexpected character of which is `'o'`… which is what your  error message says.

It seems like you've gotten confused between the literal notation in a JavaScript script, which results in an object, and the text format known as JSON, and decided that you must always "parse" objects in order to use them.

Answer (score 3):

So when you try to parse an object you will get an error. JSON.parse takes a string and parses it into an object. You already have an object, you don't need to parse it.

```
var obj = {};
JSON.parse(obj)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

JSON is not a JavaScript Object.

now if you stringify your obj, you'll get JSON back:

```
var obj = [ { id: 18, username: 'test', passwordHash: 'redacted', admin: 0, created: 'Fri Jun 13 2014 17:17:10 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)' } ];

JSON.stringify(obj);
"[{"id":18,"username":"test","passwordHash":"redacted","admin":0,"created":"Fri Jun 13 2014 17:17:10 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"}]"
```

Comment: Good description ta. I was struggling with this just yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a JavaScript object back, and it appears you are, just use it. There's no need to parse it.